# window.location called too often?

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to intercept the window.location changes to do some native work in Android app. To ve more specific, I overwrite the call in WebViewClient:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

to look for anything start with "native://". The JavaScript code is like this.

```
function callNative() {
   window.location = "native://doSomeNativeWork()";
}

function callNativeManyTimes(count) {
   for(i = 0 ; i < count ; i ++) {
       callNative();
   }
}

<a href="javascript:callNativeManyTimes(40);" class="btn large">DoSomeNativeWork</a><br/>
```

The problem I am seeing is that if I call "window.location = something" many time very quickly (like in the code above) , I will only get one call inside the WebViewClient on the native code side. If I make the call 50ms apart, I will get everyone of them. I am thinking that the browser is doing some optimization around this.

I think I can solve this problem like this: do not use window.location, change to embed a native object to javascript, and call methods on that object in javascript. I am just wondering why this is happening. Can someone more familiar wit JS to share some insight?

Thanks

Comment: "If I make the call 50ms apart, I will everyone of them." How do you make the calls 50ms apart? via window.setInterval and put the callNative() call in the code called by setInterval?

Comment: setTimeout("callNative", 50*i)

Comment: you may try to do window.location.href = "...", but this seemes to be rather strange way. Maybe, create images with such URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that loading a URL is asynchronous (it would probably be a bad idea to block the execution of a script until a URL has been resolved). As such, setting `window.location` will presumably only queue up the loading of the new URL, which will be done in a different thread.

Waiting 50ms is a hack that may or may not work. You need to find a different approach. You need something that guarantees that each one of those URLs will be resolved. If the order doesn't matter, you could just use images, like somebody suggested. Otherwise, you could use a native JavaScript interface (which is probably the better approach).

Comment: You are absolutely right, changing location is not for this kind of work. I am actually taking another approach. I just posted that question to start a discussion about the optimization browser is doing.

Comment: It's not an optimization, it's just a detached process, i.e. the JavaScript just requests a change of location, but a different thread will actually perform this change. By the time the other thread gets to perform the change, the JavaScript thread already set the location `count` times.

Answer (score 2):

I had exact the same problem. You can do that by creating iframes. I create iframes with the native urls and then I delete the iframe after 2 seconds just so we don't have too many laying around on the DOM. Worked like a charm to me. You can create as many iframes as you want.

I also included a cache buster on the iframe url, even though I'm not sure it's needed. Better safe then sorry.

```
function callNative(url){
    var _frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    _frame.width=0; _frame.height=0;_frame.frameBorder=0;
    document.body.appendChild(_frame);
    if (url.indexOf('?') >= 0){
        url = url + "&cb=";
    }else{
        url = url + "?cb=";
    }
    _frame.src = url + Math.round(Math.random()*1e16);
    // Remove the iframe
    setTimeout(function(){document.body.removeChild(_frame);}, 2000);
}

function callNativeManyTimes(count) {
   for(i = 0 ; i < count ; i ++) {
       callNative('native://doSomeNativeWork()');
   }
}
```

```
<a href="javascript:callNativeManyTimes(40);" class="btn large">DoSomeNativeWork</a><br/>
```

Note that I used the approach above on iOS. Not sure if it's exactly the same on Android, but from judging the question and other answer I guess it's the same.

Comment: I checked on android and adding an iframe does trigger the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method